# One List, multiple types

Tags: java

I have two lists:

```
    List<Person> listOfPerson = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Animal> listOfAnimal = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to do something like this:

```
    if(...) list = listOfPerson;
    else list = listOfAnimal;
```

so that I could do many operations with the List:

```
    list.get(i).getId();
    list.size();
    …
```

How to make it possible?

Comment: abstract base class, my friend.

Comment: Only if `list` is a list of some common parent type.  An interface, a base class, even `Object` (though that's pretty limiting).

Comment: Do `Animal` and `Person` both `extends` a common base `class` or `implements` an `Interface` that provide a `getId()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple ways of achieving what you want.
Use marker Interface implementation or using generics

Use marker Interface implementation
EG :

```
public interface MarkerInterface {

}

public class Person implements MarkerInterface {

}

public class Animal implements MarkerInterface {

}
```

Now you can have a list with Marker interface which can hold both objects

```
List< MarkerInterface > livingThings;
```

This can hold both values.

Or you can declare it List as Object like

```
List< Object > livingThings;
```

This can also hold both values.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in how you declare the common list that might hold either.  You have to declare it as

```
List<? extends CommonBaseClass> list;
```

For instance:

```
private static void listManipulation(boolean someBool) {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

    // Object is the only common base class of String and Integer 
    List<? extends Object> objectList = someBool ? stringList : integerList;
    System.out.println(objectList.size());
    System.out.println(objectList.get(0).toString());

    // This correctly produces an error.  
    // objectList.add("This won't work!");
}
```